# DAX use current row context to search same column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table of files that are duplicated across multiple countries, and files that are duplicated have the same filename.
I am trying to create a calculated column that looksup the “Tag” value where
File = current filename in row context AND  Geo = “us”
This would return the US tag value for a file for each duplicate file that exists in other countries. See desired result in table below.

```
File        |   Geo  |    Tag    |  Tag Lookup
FileName1   |   us   |     a     |      a
FileName1   |   jp   |     b     |      a
FileName1   |   cn   |     c     |      a
FileName2   |   us   |     e     |      e
FileName2   |   jp   |     f     |      e
FileName2   |   cn   |     g     |      e
```

I tried doing using a lookupvalue  formula

```
Tag Lookup = LOOKUPVALUE( Table1[Tag] , Table1[Geo] , "us" , Table1[File] , Table1[File] )
```

My assumption was that the search_columnName2 instance of Table1[File] would act as the column lookup, and the search_value of Table1[File] would interpret it as the scalar value of the current rows context... but when I try the formula I get the error: "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected".

I then tried

```
CALCULATE(
    VALUES( Table1[Tag] ) , 
    FILTER( 
        Table1 ,
        Table1[Geo] = "us" && 
        Table1[File] = Table1[File] 
    )
 )
```

But in this case I get the error: "A circular dependency was detected"

How can I perform a lookup / retrieve a value from within the same table, using a column's current context as part of the search?

Comment: Your lookup calculated column works fine for me on your example data. Do you have any files with multiple tags associate with `us`?

Comment: @AlexisOlson after looking back through the data, yes there were duplicate file+geo combinations that were causing the issue. Applying a remove duplicate rows to the table made the formula work.